# How to parse out in R?

Tags: r

I have a blurb of text in 500 rows in 1 of the many columns as below:

```
{'Smart Remote': ['Yes'], 'Color Screen': ['Yes'], 'RF Capable': ['Yes'], 'Internet Access': ['Yes']}
```

I need to append number of columns like this:

> Smart Remote : Yes, Color Screen : Yes, RF Capable : Yes, Internet
> Access : Yes

Note that entries in `{}` are random in order, with few unique entries per row

Edit : Added image snip of data set

[image]

Comment: That's JSON data, you may use the [jsonlite](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jsonlite/) package to parse/deparse.

Comment: Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Answer (score 0):

Sample data, I hope this is close enough to what you have:

```r
dat <- structure(list(id = 1:2, txt = c("{'Smart Remote': ['Yes'], 'Color Screen': ['Yes'], 'RF Capable': ['Yes'], 'Internet Access': ['Yes']}", "{'RF Capable': ['No'], 'Internet Access': ['No'],'Smart Remote': ['No'], 'Color Screen': ['No']}")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

(Note that I varied the data and the order of the fields.)

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
# library(tidyr) # unnest
# library(jsonlite) # fromJSON
dat %>%
  mutate(data = lapply(txt, \(x) data.frame(jsonlite::fromJSON(gsub("'", '"', x)), check.names = FALSE))) %>%
  tidyr::unnest(data)
# # A tibble: 2 x 6
#      id txt                                                                                                   `Smart Remote` `Color Screen` `RF Capable` `Internet Access`
#   <int> <chr>                                                                                                 <chr>          <chr>          <chr>        <chr>            
# 1     1 {'Smart Remote': ['Yes'], 'Color Screen': ['Yes'], 'RF Capable': ['Yes'], 'Internet Access': ['Yes']} Yes            Yes            Yes          Yes              
# 2     2 {'RF Capable': ['No'], 'Internet Access': ['No'],'Smart Remote': ['No'], 'Color Screen': ['No']}      No             No             No           No
```

### data.table

```r
library(data.table)
# library(jsonlite) # fromJSON
DT <- as.data.table(dat)
DT[, c(.SD, rbindlist(lapply(txt, \(x) jsonlite::fromJSON(gsub("'", '"', x))), use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE))]
#       id                                     txt Smart Remote Color Screen RF Capable Internet Access
#    <int>                                  <char>       <char>       <char>     <char>          <char>
# 1:     1 {'Smart Remote': ['Yes'], 'Color Scr...          Yes          Yes        Yes             Yes
# 2:     2 {'RF Capable': ['No'], 'Internet Acc...           No           No         No              No
```

Comment: Thanks, but there are breaks in the code when I try to mod. Ive added image snip of dataset

Comment: Sure, but ... I am not spending time trying to transcribe an image of data into something useful. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info for many discussions on how to provide data that we can use.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is supposed to be JSON, there is an error in it: quotes around a JSON object should **always** be double quotes, while this data uses *mostly* single quotes. As such, R's JSON libraries can't seem to load it.

We can't just replace all single quotes with double quotes: this data uses double quotes whenever there are single quotes inside a string; we need to make sure that those single quotes remain untouched:

> [image]

#### Replacing ' with "

From the excerpt we can distill the task of this transformation:

`in:`  `{'Details':["We'll facilitate"]}`
`out:` `{'Details':['We\'ll facilitate']}`

We don't know yet what the input looks like when two types of quotes are present in a string:

- `{'Details':["We'll facilitate \"everything\" "]}` or
- `{'Details':['We\'ll facilitate "everything" ']}`
- or maybe some completely different way of escaping.

For now I'll handle just the first transformation, and ignore the second.

The function below walks through a string, remembers if we're inside single or double quotes, and changes single quotes to double quotes accordingly:

```r
repairString <- function(string) {
  
  cat('in:', string, '\n')
  
  inside <- FALSE  # store if we're inside single / double quotes or none at all
  i <- 1           # string index
  
  while(i <= nchar(string)) {
    
    chr <- substr(string, i, i)  # get single character
    
    if(chr %in% c("'", '"')) {   # check if ' or "
      
      if(isFALSE(inside)) {      # not yet inside quotes: we're entering them
        inside <- chr
        swap <- TRUE
        
      } else if(inside == chr) { # inside the same quotes: we're exiting them now
        inside <- FALSE
        swap <- TRUE
        
      } else {                   # inside the other type of quote: we need to skip this one
        swap <- FALSE
      }
      
      # swap ' for " if required
      if(swap & chr == "'") string <- paste0(substr(string, 1, i-1), '"', substr(string, i+1, nchar(string)))
  
    }
    i <- i+1
  }
  
  cat('out:',string,'\n\n')
  return(string)
  
}
```

Example:

```r
> repairString("{'Details':[\"We'll facilitate\"]}")

in: {'Details':["We'll facilitate"]} 
out: {"Details":["We'll facilitate"]}
```

For this small example dataset I mocked up, we can use this function to repair all strings and store them in the data frame:

```r
df <- structure(list(features = c("{'Smart Remote': ['Yes'], 'Color Screen': ['Yes'], 'RF Capable': ['Yes'], 'Internet Access': ['Yes']}", 
                                  "{'Hypergalactic': ['No'], 'Waterproof': ['No','Well, sometimes'], 'Good With Dogs': [\"No they're very bad with dogs\"]}"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))

df$features.fixed <- lapply(df$features, repairString)
```

Result:
[image]

#### Printing the data

Now that the strings are repaired, they can be read, parsed, stored and printed:

```r
# iterate over all rows
lapply(df$features.fixed, function(row) {
  
  # parse JSON
  row_data <- jsonlite::fromJSON(row, simplifyVector = F)
  
  # join multiple values with ' / '
  row_data <- mapply(function(x) paste0(unlist(x), collapse=' / '), row_data)
  
  # paste names and values together
  text <- sapply(seq_along(row_data), function(x) paste0(names(row_data)[x], ': ', row_data[x]) )
  
  # paste multiple 'name: value' strings together
  paste0(text, collapse = '; ')
  
}) -> df$features.string
```

```r
> df$features.string
[[1]]
[1] "Smart Remote: Yes; Color Screen: Yes; RF Capable: Yes; Internet Access: Yes"

[[2]]
[1] "Hypergalactic: No; Waterproof: No / Well, sometimes; Good With Dogs: No they're very bad with dogs"
```